# Windows 7 after updates stops booting

Tags: windows-7

It just freezes before 4 particles appears with text

```
Starting Windows...
```

Running in safe mode - it hungs up with last line of text indicating that it is trying to load `ataport.sys` driver.

Using 32-bit currently, previously had 64-bit. No difference.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have/can you perform a system restore to a point before the update was applied? (You might find booting with a Windows 7 CD makes this easier). This might get your system working again.

Then, look at my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/171794/prevent-windows-7-from-installing-a-critical-updates-that-crashes-the-system/171804#171804) to see how to "hide" that update so it is not installed again in the future (or don't if you wish to try again in case it was a failed install, not a conflicting update).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to do a system restore on an unbootable PC, this article is for Vista but is the same for W7

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial142.html