# When booting Windows 7, everytime a sceen appears for 10 minutes "configuring updates 0%" before continuing

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, wait

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop Windows 7 from installing some updates which aren't working?](https://superuser.com/questions/194719/stop-windows-7-from-installing-some-updates-which-arent-working)
>   [Prevent Windows 7 from installing a “critical” updates that crashes the system.](https://superuser.com/questions/171794/prevent-windows-7-from-installing-a-critical-updates-that-crashes-the-system)
>   [Windows Update Failure](https://superuser.com/questions/194522/windows-update-failure)

Has anyone experienced something like that? Could't dfind anything about that behaviour in the MS Knowledge Base. This drives me crazy ;)

Comment: Not a programming-related question, voting to move to superuser.com

Comment: Voted to move to superuser - not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Not only is this *NOT* an exact duplicate, it bears only passing resemblance to the referenced question. Additionally, the answer offered by @Moab is completely different than the advice in the aforementioned "solution." The other problem appears to refer to a one-time occurance while this one seems to be a repeating issue.

Comment: It is however a dupe of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/194719/stop-windows-7-from-installing-some-updates-which-arent-working) question, but that is also closed as a dupe - possibly that link should be reopened as there's maybe a wider problem here that needs coverage?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the pending.xml located here  C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml

.