# Stop Windows 7 from installing some updates which aren't working?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Windows Update Failure](https://superuser.com/questions/194522/windows-update-failure)
>   [Prevent Windows 7 from installing a “critical” updates that crashes the system.](https://superuser.com/questions/171794/prevent-windows-7-from-installing-a-critical-updates-that-crashes-the-system)

My parents Dell Zino (running 64-bit Windows 7) has developed a problem where every single time they turn it on they get the "Configuring Updates" message for approximately 10 minutes and every time they shut the computer down, Windows 7 insists on installing 3 updates.

This has now being going on for a couple of days.

Given that I can only diagnose and troubleshoot problems remotely using LogMeIn (which means no safe mode), my plan was to see if I can find the three updates, download them manually and install them one at a time.

However I'm not sure how I can stop Windows from trying to install the current three updates. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: As per the comments on [this](http://superuser.com/questions/194676/when-booting-windows-7-everytime-a-sceen-appears-for-10-minutes-configuring-upd) question I'm now voting to re-open this...

Comment: @DMA I disagree with the re-opening. Both questions point to Windows Update Failure, which should be the canonical question in this case.

Comment: @Diago, not quite, the update failure Q is about Windows throwing an error, this doesn't and just cycles so will potentially have a different solution. And as per it being [raised again](http://superuser.com/questions/194676/when-booting-windows-7-everytime-a-sceen-appears-for-10-minutes-configuring-upd) I wondered if it warranted separate investigation. That's my take on it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into Windows Update and right click on the update you do not want to install you will be given the option to Hide the update.
This will stop it from trying to install again.
Hope this helps